# cpSpaceAddCollisionHandler compiler warning question

Tags: handler, collision, chipmunk

I have the following in my program (which seems to be working perfectly), but causes a compiler warning:

> Passing argument 7 of cpSpaceAddCollisionHandler from incompatible pointer type.

```
cpSpaceAddCollisionHandler(space, COLLISION_TYPE_BALL, COLLISION_TYPE_LEFT_WALL, collisionBallWallBegin, nil, nil, collisionBallWallEnd, self);
```

`collisionBallWallBegin` does not cause this warning and the two methods are declared the same:

```
static int collisionBallWallBegin (cpArbiter *arb, cpSpace *space, void *data)
```

and

```
static int collisionBallWallEnd(cpArbiter *arb, cpSpace *space, void *data)
```

I can't figure out why I am getting the warning and it is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

`begin` needs to be a `cpCollisionBeginFunc`, which takes three arguments and returns a `cpBool`.

In comparison, `separate` needs to be a `cpCollisionSeparateFunc`, which takes three arguments and *does not return a value*.

Comment: Live by the cut and paste...die by the cut and paste.  I have stared at that for hours and was never going to see the int vs void!  Thank you!!